# Counting the occurrence of one dataframe column as a substring in another?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, substring

I'm new to python and have found answers for counting hardcoded substrings in a df column but am unable to find an answer when using another df column as input. Is this possible with pandas?

It's quite messy but essentially my dataframe is:

```
ID    Info
3457  <type1><stats></id>3457<type2></id>3457<type2></id>45
234   <type2><stats></id>234
4555  <type2><stats></id>604555<type1></id>4555<type2></id>4555
2378  <stats></id>555
```

I've managed to count the occurrences of specific strings e.g

```
df['Type1_Count']=df['Info'].apply((lambda string: string.count("<type1>")))
df['Type2_Count']=df['Info'].apply((lambda string: string.count("<type2>")))
```

However I also need to count the occurrence of the ID's from the first column and since these can have a false match it would really need to be a count of the string "/id>" plus the **ID** column.

Hope this makes sense, appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of these

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['bernard','Samy','yyy'],'digit':[2,3,3],'SearchID':['be','xx','Sam']})
print df

for ID in df['SearchID']:
    print ID, '\n', df.name.str.count(ID)

Searchstr = df['SearchID'].str.cat(sep='|')
print df.apply(lambda x: x['name'].count(x['SearchID']), axis=1)
```

Comment: For the first method I get the error "TypeError: first argument must be string or compiled pattern"

For the second method gives me "AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas" possibly because my SearchID is int64?

Do I need to convert the datatypes?

Comment: Yes , string is required for this kind of functions , convert them to string and then try